# Recreating Dir failed with error during deployment in Elastic BeanStalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

Im facing this error during the deployment of my nodejs project in elasticbeanstalk. Any idea how can I resolve this?

```
2020/06/19 11:07:39.284255 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [StageApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: Recreating Dir failed with error: unlinkat /var/app/staging/node_modules/@gryffindor/beacon-service/node_modules: directory not empty 
2020/06/19 11:07:39.284331 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[]}]}
```